# Oracle Apex 3.0 : In a Tree region, how to keep only one path expanded?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Here is an example showing a tree menu built in Oracle APEX :

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=41928:4:15843695212543::NO::P4_EMPLOYEE_ID:120

If you keep expanding all the child nodes, the tree will become higher and higher.

**Now I want to** collapse all other paths but only keep the path I clicked expanded, for example, in the demo page, after expanding Node 1, when I click Node 2.

What should I do to collapse Node1 but keep Node 2 expanded?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about oracle specifically, but when you click on one, you could loop through every node and collapse it if it is expanded, THEN in the same function expand the node you clicked on after the others have been collapsed. If you expand it first, collapsing every node will collapse the one you just expanded

Comment: The example in your URL is not behaving the same way you are explaining. I am able to expand all nodes at once without the upper node collapsing. I think in your case the frame size needs to be checked. If the tree is in a restricted frame size then auto resize might be the reason.

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=41928:4:116880172691481:EXPAND,122

Comment: @Annjawn I was not explaining how the example is working, I was describing how I want the tree to work. The URL example is what I have now. This tree is generated from a SQL query within a Oracle APEX tree region, whether the nodes expanded or not has nothing to do with the frame size.